# Allowing access to certain Wordpress created pages or posts with htaccess / htpasswd

Tags: htaccess, security, user-access

Trying to figure out how to give access to a certain page, lets say `http://mypage.com/page` and not letting people access the main index via `http://mypage.com`. Or just simply disallow access to `http://mypage.com` and let people be able to input whatever subdirectory they want and let through if the page do exist. Is this possible to achieve with Wordpress?

`/page` is created by Wordpress and not some HTML page I want to give access to.

Tried this but with no luck

```
AuthUserFile path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "Gone fishin', come back soon"
AuthType Basic
<Files "index.php">
  require valid-user
</Files>
```

Comment: If you want to implement this on `.htaccess` level that is not really specific to WordPress and would be better asked at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Rarst You might be right. The reason I posted here was because there's already some .htaccess interaction happening within Wordpress, how posts and pages are assigned. Thus I figured it's somehow Wordpress specific how htaccess handles these rewrites.

Comment: While WP does use `.htaccess` rules (which is essential for pretty permalinks) what you are trying to do is unlikely to intersect with that.